# ImportError: cannot import name 'Element'

Tags: python, importerror, radix, uno

When importing an error occurs.

```
>>> import uno

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
import uno
File "C:\Users\viktor.zaichenko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-   32\lib\site-packages\uno\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from base import Element, Css, Payload, UnoBaseFeature, UnoBaseField
ImportError: cannot import name 'Element'

>>>
```

Which modules this item? Installation base and python-base is not helps.

Comment: Do you have a file named `base.py` in the currect directory?

Comment: I have a file named base.py in the currect directory.

Comment: Your `base.py` is conflicting with another file of the same name in the `uno` package.  Can you rename your `base.py` to something else?

Comment: I renamed base.py to base0.py but it is not works

Comment: Do you also have `base.pyc`?  If so, remove it.

Comment: I have not base.pyc

Answer (score -1):

You have to install python-uno or python3-uno depend on your version of office 
just type 
apt install python3-uno